# GDB commits suicide (kills debugged process out of a sudden)

Tags: gdb

I'm running a very large app (binary has 2GB, mostly because of debug symbols) through GDB (version 7.12, Ubuntu 14.04) so I can catch all crashes and have full backtraces + coredumps:
`ulimit -c unlimited`
and `bt / bt full / info thread / generate-core-file` after crash.

However, rarely I get some strange behaviour: app instantly closes with `Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.` in log, however I'm 100% positive nothing else from the system kills it, the one responsible being GDB for this. When this happens, it doesn't generate any backtrace / coredump / etc.

As far as I saw until now, this happens at big (1day) uptimes. Whenever a normal crash happens at ~1 day uptime (I'm not talking about the kill situation, but normal crash) and GDB generates the backtrace + coredump, the coredump size is ~100GB. So only thing to assume for now is GDB is consuming too much memory to handle it. Unfortunately I don't know the exact memory usage when this happens (since it's unexpected), but the swap file is almost empty, which most likely means it didn't really run out of memory.

Thoughts on how to debug this situation?

Comment: This is probably OOM killer. Look at `dmesg` output for something like this: `Out of memory: Kill process`.

Comment: You are right, checked dmesg log and I found `ps invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1042d0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0` `Out of memory: Kill process 8057 (MY_BINARY_NAME_HERE) score 909 or sacrifice child` for everytime this happened. Add a separate answer so I can accept it. In the mean time, any thoughts on why the swap would be empty? I would have expected it to be full in this scenario. Or maybe it was full with the same process's memory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> binary has 2GB

You are likely running out of memory and you app was likely killed by OOM killer. To confirm this look at `dmesg` output for `oom-killer` and `Killed process` messages.

> but the swap file is almost empty, which most likely means it didn't
>   really run out of memory

This depends on `vm.swappiness` value in proc. Try to increase this parameter to increase how aggressively the kernel will swap memory pages. See [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
   /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
          The value in this file controls how aggressively the kernel
          will swap memory pages.  Higher values increase
          aggressiveness, lower values decrease aggressiveness.  The
          default value is 60.
```

Comment: Thanks. I never would have figured this out because my eyes were filled with tears of rage at gdb.